# SQL Select Statement Not Giving Expected Results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to write a select statement to show the top 10 actors in all the Sci-Fi related genres. Instead, I'm getting the top 10 actors overall and ALL of the titles they've had, not just in Sci-Fi (which is what I want).

```
select top 10 people_name as actor_name, count(tg_genre_name) as number_of_titles
from nf_people
    join nf_cast on people_id=cast_people_id
    join nf_titles on cast_title_id=title_id
    join nf_title_genres on title_id=tg_title_id
where tg_genre_name like '%Sci-Fi%'
group by people_name
order by number_of_titles desc
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using LIKE over straight equality for the genre?

Comment: The query looks OK to me

Comment: Well, that's how I was taught to do it. Also, if I use = I get an empty table, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Ok well thats a problem... do you have a space before or after 'sci-fi' in the database...check for special characters if this database was filled using an import of some kind.

Comment: Well, there's a couple of different genres that have 'sci-fi' in them... 'Action Sci-Fi & Fantasy', 'Alien Sci-Fi'.

Comment: please provide sample data, as in what is the output and expected output that you want

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10 M.actor_name,  count(*) as number_of_titles FROM
(
  SELECT people_name AS actor_name
  FROM nf_people
       JOIN nf_cast ON people_id=cast_people_id
       JOIN nf_titles ON cast_title_id=title_id
       JOIN nf_title_genres ON title_id=tg_title_id
  WHERE tg_genre_name LIKE '%Sci-Fi%'
) AS M
GROUP BY M.actor_name
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Comment: I just modified my answer I had the wrong field in the group by.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing `WHERE` with `HAVING`.

With `WHERE` it's selecting all authors that could have Sci-Fi.  `HAVING` restricts the query as you are looking for.

Comment: Can someone let me know why this was down voted? - am relatively new to answering questions and will stop answering if this is what happens

Comment: Have you tried writing a query with *HAVING* resolving the author's problem ? Because with *HAVING* you are filtering out AFTER the aggregate occurs, so you'll count unwanted records

Comment: I am guessing that you would not really be able to fully know that the question can be answered by using HAVING. What I have always done is that if you think you might know an answer then leave a comment asking if the questioner has tried that. If that solves the problem, you can always put it as an answer.

Comment: `HAVING` applied to the records after GROUP BY and usually is used for check for result of aggregates, but author of the question needs filter records before GROUP BY, and it is not necessary to receive all authors from database group them and only after that filter by genre.